# Как запросом удалить все записи из выбранной таблицы?

Tags: python, sqlite

Пробую так:

```
def deleteall(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('position.dms')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('DELETE FROM `servo_9`')
```

Код выполняется без ошибок, но все записи остаются на месте.

Comment: Напишите полностью код, этот кусочек ни о чем не говорит

Comment: Вы сами же написали ответ в тексте вопроса. Поясните, в чём вопрос-то и почему это не работает?

Comment: код исполняется профита от него не вижу .столбцы на месте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> код исполняется профита от него не вижу .столбцы на месте

чтобы удалились **строки** добавьте:

```
conn.commit()
```

после вызова:

```
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM `servo_9`')
```

**столбцы** при помощи `delete from` не удаляются - для этого придется [пересоздавать таблицу, т.к. `SQLite` не поддерживает `ALTER TABLE tab_name DROP COLUMN col_name`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8442173/5741205)

Answer (score 1):

`delete from "table"` это правильный sql, если вы хотите все записи из таблицы удалить. Осталось только вызвать commit, чтобы завершить transaction. Для этого можно context manager использовать (при выходе либо commit либо rollback (в случае исключения) будет вызван):

```
with conn:
    conn.execute('delete from "table"')
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/3YpvI0).